# bootstrap issue inside frameset frame

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari, frameset

Am currently developing a page with Bootstrap 3.1.1 that will be delivered through an Enterprise LMS (CSOD) as a learning module and am experiencing an issue with how it scales on IOS devices.

Once loaded into the LMS the page responds perfectly when viewed in a desktop browser, but when viewed in IOS the page defaults to a 992px width (no matter what the actual screen width) and zooms to fit the content in rather than responding normally. This happens on both an iPad and iPhone.

I'm confident that this issue lies not with the code of the actual page but in how the page is being loaded by the LMS (have tested the page on a normal webserver and it works perfectly across all devices).

When accessing the page through the system, the LMS will actually load a 'Launch' page with a series of frames, and then load the source content into the 'Lesson' frame:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<title>Launch</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="0,0,0,*0" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
<frame name="frmRqst" id="frmRqst" src="ScormRequest.aspx?s=123465abc2" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">
<frame name="frmRsltGet" id="frmRsltGet" src="result.htm" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">
<frame name="frmRsltPut" id="frmRsltPut" src="result.htm" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">
<frame name="lesson" id="lesson" src="result.htm"?>
<frame id="frmApi" src="ScormLms.aspx?s=123456abc2&c=" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Now as this is an Enterprise system I have absolutely no chance of making any changes to how the LMS loads he page or to the code above.

So my question is, can I include anything in my source code that could change or override the frame settings of the ‘Launch’ page and ensure a smooth repsonsive page across devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider not using <frameset> since it is not supported in HTML5.

Comment: Unfortunately the frameset tag forms part of an enterprise system that can't be changed and we have to work with